# Scroll to a section on the same page from the URL nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with nextjs 12.2.5, I created a section with a specific ID, in order to be able to redirect users directly to it, but the problem is that every time I entered the URL with the anchor and the id of the section, for example, http://localhost:3000/mx#contact-form, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

I have tried the following implementations with no success:

**scrollToSection.ts**

```
export const scrollToSection = () => {
  const anchor = window.location.hash;
  if (!anchor) return;
  const element = document.querySelector(anchor);
  if (element && typeof document !== 'undefined')
    element.scrollIntoView();
};
```

**Then on my page.tsx**

```
.....
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
   router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', scrollToSection);

   return () => {
     router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', scrollToSection);
  };
}, []);
.....
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of debugging, I realized that the issue wasn't to append "#contact-form" to the URL, it was related to it, but the hydration mismatch was caused for a component in the header, this component was extracting the country param from the URL using

```
router.asPath.split("/")[0]
```

And the issue here is that this line was extracting not only the country prefix from mysite.com/es#contact-form but all the lines including #contact-form.

So there was a component that was rendered in the first load, but then was disappearing because this component was expecting a country prefix, and es#contact-form is not a valid one.

I fix this by getting the country from the router params instead of from the asPath, as it was already included in the route params in page [country].tsx